# how to read from web socket or socket using codename one?

Tags: codenameone

I want to develop a mobile app to communicate with a simple server, such as node.js.  I would like it to be more real time than post/get, so would like to use socket.io, or failing that web sockets, or failing that real sockets.  Are any of these possible with code name one?  A native app with no push/real time updates would be worse than a HTML5 app.

Answer (score 0):

Codename One supports push notification http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/07/pushing-it.html

It doesn't at the time of this writing support sockets. However, its possible to use native code in Codename One to invoke socket code in the native platform.

The reason web UI's are slow have very little to do with socket/network and more to do with reflow http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/07/why-mobile-web-is-slow.html